# Fetch FTP url via HTTP with Python through HTTP proxy

Tags: python, proxy, ftp

I need to fetch an FTP url via HTTP with Python. I have to do so via an HTTP proxy that returns the destination FTP listing as an HTML page.

I've tried Requests and ftplib, but they both look at the protocol and try to use the FTP proxy, rather than the HTTP proxy.

I need Python to ignore the protocol in the supplied URL and just hand the requested URL on to the HTTP proxy server via an HTTP GET.

Here's an example wget session that I'm trying to reproduce in Python:

```
Connecting to PROXY connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000055f4bc243ed0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET ftp://ftp.mcafee.com/commonupdater/current/vscandat1000/dat/0000/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.2 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: ftp.mcafee.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Via: 1.1 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 20494
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
URI content encoding = ‘utf-8’
Length: 20494 (20K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

Comment: Did you consider opening a plain socket to the proxy and sending the HTTP request?

Answer (score 1):

Using httplib you can force an HTTP connection via a proxy for any URL regardless of protocol.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(proxy_host, proxy_port)
conn.request("GET", ftp_url)
resp = conn.getresponse()
body = resp.read()
```